# How can I get Unity to set file info of an exe as part of the build?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How can I set file info details of an exe such as Product name, Product version and Copyright (see image) in Unity after building it into an exe file?

[image: Details]

Comment: Interesting that this picture seems to come from [here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-modify-properties-of-final-compiled-exe-file-on-the-windows-standalone-platform.581383/) where there is already an answer.

Comment: Yeah thats true but that doesnt fix my problem.